# Android Viewpager fragments refreshed when swiped

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am new in Android and I don't really understand why a `Fragment`'s content which was added dynamically (for example some image which was added after a button click) is disappearing after scrolling some count of `Fragment`s and then come back.

There is really simple code `Activity` and `Fragment`:

```java
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            getView().findViewById(R.id.clickMeButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getView().findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    class CustomAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private List<CustomFragment> fragments = Arrays.asList(
            new CustomFragment(),
            new CustomFragment(),
            new CustomFragment()
        );

        public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return fragments.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }
    }

}
```

and appropriate xmls:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/clickMeButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="click me"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logic is simple. On each `Fragment` I can click on a `Button` and as result an image appears.

And it works. *But* ...

When I show image on the first fragment, then scroll to the third one and come back to first one again image is gone.

What should I do to prevent this ? Should I somehow save state of visibility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` releases the memory associated with a `Fragment` when it is scrolled out of view. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html):

> When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be
>   destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows
>   the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited
>   page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially
>   more overhead when switching between pages.

You can try one of the following four options:

**1.** Since you have a small number of pages, you can use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. `FragmentPagerAdapter` holds onto the created `Fragment`s and does not destroy them on swipe.

**2.** In your `Fragment`, store a `boolean` in a `SharedPreference` and set (or clear) its value when you make the image visible or invisible. Then in the `onResume()` method of your `Fragment`, make the image visible or invisible based on the value of the `SharedPreference`.

**3.** In the `onCreate()` of your `Fragment`, call `setRetainInstance(true);`.

**4.** If the number of fragments is fixed & relatively small, then in your `onCreate()` add the following code:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);         /* limit is a fixed integer*/
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've tried 1 and 3 items (except 2nd) but result is the same. Is it some other way to store fragments without removing from memory? I need to implement something similar to tabs in web browser. So I will use WebView for that. Of course I can store in SharedPreferences page the user selected. But it all the time will be loading of that page. That is not really correct. So I need exactly keep fragment in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Whats happening is

Since you are using adapter there may be a number of fragments active at a time like 3 or 4 for example.

Adapter will render the views dynamically to reduce the memory usage. In your case

`Fragment 1 -> Fragment 2 - > Fragment 3`

Let the active fragment be 3 now, So `Fragment 1` may be removed from memory when you scroll back , it will redraw the fragment by

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

So the image is still `invisible` and in its initial stage.

`Answer`

Set a flag to identify the status of the image and use it in `onCreateView()` to make it `visible` or `invisible`.

**UPDATE**

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(yourLimit);
```

`yourLimit` is the number of fragments you want to keep alive which is not in screen currently.

**NOTE:** This is memory intensive.

Comment: thanks for reply, but maybe there is some way to exactly keep fragment on memory without recreating? I need to use WebView component to implement something similar to tabs in web-browser. But fragment recreation will all the time load the page

Answer (score 1):

save the visibility of image in `onSaveInstance` method of your fragment class `CustomFragment`. Override onSaveInstanceState in the fragment activity class `onSaveInstanceState` call super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle) in that overridden method

```
     @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

       super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       outState.putString("visibility", visibility);
      }
```

Then you can retain the state in the `onActivityCreated` method of your fragment class `CustomFragment`

```
int visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
            visibility = savedInstanceState.getInt("visibility");
        getView().findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(visibility);
        getView().findViewById(R.id.clickMeButton)
        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getView().findViewById(R.id.image).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but may be there is some way just to keep fragment in memory without fragment recreating

Comment: If you have fix and relatively small number of Fragment `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfFragment)`

Answer (score 1):

> mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);

It worked for me thanks !
I had a viewpager with 3 fragments and a recyclerview in the first one. When i clicked on the last one my recyclerview disappeared..

Not checked yet about performance