# ViewPager layout when scrolling, components in layout are empty

Tags: android

**Edit;**

I solved my problem with option 4

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217695/6744524

i am using ViewPager with 5 layouts , I have a few Edittext elements in each layout.

I write to Edittext in layout 1, but when I scroll to ViewPager and come to layout 3, everything I write to Edittext in layout 1 disappears.

how do I prevent this from happening?

```
layouts = new int[]{
        R.layout.potansiyel_slide1,
        R.layout.potansiyel_slide2,
        R.layout.potansiyel_slide3,
        R.layout.potansiyel_slide4,
        R.layout.potansiyel_slide5
};



public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);
        CreateComponets(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == obj;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View) object;
        container.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try **`setOffscreenPageLimit()`**? Wherever you instantiate  `MyViewPagerAdapter` in `Activity` or `Fragment` just try with this `MyViewPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter()   mPagerAdapter.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)`. Please try and confirm.

Comment: @iCantC I solved my problem, thank you for reply

Comment: Just professionally curious, what was the issue and how you solved it?

Comment: @iCantC i wrote above

Comment: Yeah, thanks mate. Glad that the answer you referenced matched with my comment.